# Church Using foldr

Tags: haskell

I came across this code and it works but I don't know why. I will attempt to convey the parts that I understand but I don't get the full picture. Here is the code:

```
church :: Int -> (c -> c) -> c -> c
church 0 _ arg = arg
church n f arg = foldr (\x acc -> f acc) arg [1..n]
```

When running this input on the Prelude,

```
church 4 tail "ABCDEFGH"
```

this is the answer:

```
"EFGH"
```

I know how foldr works, I can walk through an example of foldr:

```
foldr (/) 2 [8,12,24,4]
```

What happens here is:

```
4/2 = 2, 24/2 = 12, 12/12 = 1, 8/1 = 8
```

I get the desired output 8, as described in the second example of [this page](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/foldr_f.html):

As for this question, I know why "EFGH" is the answer. The tail is applied four times and it goes like this:

```
tail "ABCDEFGH" = "BCDEFGH", 
tail "BCDEFGH" = "CDEFGH"
tail "CDEFGH" = "DEFGH"
tail "DEFGH" = "EFGH"
```

But, in this code, this is the procedure when I write it out:

```
foldr (\x acc -> tail acc) "ABCDEFGH" [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

From what I have described for `foldr` above, `foldr` applies tail and `"ABCDEFGH"` to 4, since 4 is the last element. But, I can't wrap my head around how `"ABCDEFGH"` is applied with a tail to 4. From my example, it was easy because `(/)` divides 2 elements, one from the list and the other being the second argument. However, in this code's case, tail is used between an element from a list and another list. I do not understand that. Can anybody help me out by going through element by element, like how I described in my example?

Comment: The function generates a list of 1 to N which in  terms of foldr is doing the operation 4 times over the list but in this case the `x` is actually ignored and the operation is only done on the `arg` which in your case is the primary input

Comment: Oh I see, that's a great explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `x` isn't used anywhere to the right of the `->`. Thus, the numbers in the list aren't being used. It could be a list of units and still work the same: `foldr (\x acc -> tail acc) "ABCDEFGH" [(), (), (), ()]` The only purpose of the list is to encode the number of times to do `tail` in its length. It may also help your understanding if you replace `\x acc -> tail acc` with the equivalent expression `const tail`.